# Generate QR codes in .xsl?

Tags: java, xml, xslt, qr-code

How can I generate a QR code from XSL?

I have the following information in an .xsl file and I need to generate a qr code, in the same file with the same data.

```
            <!-- Inicio PDF417 -->
            <xsl:if test="string-length(normalize-space($PDF417))!=0">
                <fo:block-container absolute-position="absolute" left="13.1cm" top="24.5cm" width="6.2cm" height="2.2cm" border="0pt solid" text-align="center">
                    <fo:block>
                        <fo:instream-foreign-object content-width="6.2cm" content-height="2.2cm">
                            <j4lbarcode xmlns="http://java4less.com/j4lbarcode/fop" mode="inline">
                                <pdf417>
                                    <code>
                                        <xsl:value-of select="$PDF417"/>
                                    </code>
                                    <rows>0</rows>
                                    <maxRows>200</maxRows>
                                    <cols>0</cols>
                                    <ecLevel>5</ecLevel>
                                    <compaction>BINARY</compaction>
                                    <X>0</X>
                                    <H>2</H>
                                    <margin>0</margin>
                                </pdf417>
                            </j4lbarcode>
                        </fo:instream-foreign-object>
                    </fo:block>
                </fo:block-container>
            </xsl:if>
            <!-- Fin PDF417 -->
```

Can anybody help me, 
TY

Comment: It looks like you're using the J4L Barcodes plugin for Apache FOP. Have you looked at [this page](http://www.java4less.com/barcodes/barcodes.php?info=FOPPlugin_Guide)? There's a QRCode example about half way down the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.java4less.com/barcodes/barcodes.php?info=FOPPlugin_Guide

Ensure that you have the qrcode.jar on your classpath:

> In order to use the plugin in your FOP documents you need to add the following jars to your classpath:
>
> - rbarcode-fop.jar
> - rbarcode.jar
> - qrcode.jar ( if you need to create QRCode barcodes)

Below is modeled from the example in the documentation that uses the value of the `$PDF417` variable. I'm not familiar if any of the other elements from your `pdf417` element could also be applied, but that should be enough to get started.

```
<fo:instream-foreign-object >
  <j4lbarcode xmlns="http://java4less.com/j4lbarcode/fop" mode="inline">
    <qrcode>
      <code><xsl:value-of select="$PDF417"/></code>
      <moduleSize>2</moduleSize>
      <processTilde>false</processTilde>
      <margin>30</margin> 
      <ecLevel>H</ecLevel> 
      <encoding>AUTO</encoding>
      <configuration>1</configuration>
    </qrcode>
  </j4lbarcode>
</fo:instream-foreign-object>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, I am very focused, although I solved the problem in another way (Creating the code directly from java).